# JavaScript to add a row and change previous button name

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, row

How can I add a new row of data to a table but change the previous button to delete?

here is an example of what I currently have:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZmDu5/1/

What I am trying to do is that when the user first comes in they fill in the first row with data such as:

checked box, name, make a selection, something, something else, and select one of the radio buttons and then when they click on add I want to add a new row of empty cells but change the add row button for the previous row to say delete and keep going until a submit button is clicked

Comment: Are you sure about the jsfiddle you attached?

Comment: should be: http://jsfiddle.net/ZmDu5/1/